# Javascript: Store an image in an array by clicking the image in the gallery

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to solve the following steps: store image(s) in array for later use. I am really experiencing difficulties I don't know where to start.

I have created a small gallery using picsum; when the user clicks on an image; the image needs to be stored in a new array [of images].

https://codepen.io/aaron_1986/pen/oNyborW?editors=1010

```
<img src="" id="ggg">
<img src="" id="ggg">
<img src="" id="ggg">
<img src="" id="ggg">
<img src="" id="ggg">
<div id="text">
</div>
```

JS

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const img = document.getElementById("ggg");
  img.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/301?id=" + i;
  document.body.appendChild(img);

  img.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(i); 
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
 })
}
```

Comment: `id`'s must be unique. There's multiple "ggg" `id`'s in the code. Only the first `id` gets the event listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array. Use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and its [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to loop over IMG elements. Update `img.src`. Use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add `img.src` to array when an image is clicked. Give user feedback.

```js
let selected_images = [];
document.querySelectorAll('.ggg').forEach(function (img, idx) {
  img.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/301?id=" + idx;

  img.addEventListener("click", function({target: src}) {
  
    // check for existing img.src in array
    if ( !selected_images.includes(src) ) {
      // append to array if not found
      selected_images.push(src);
    }
    
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = `YOU CLICKED ${idx + 1}`;
    console.log(selected_images);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="text">&nbsp;</div>
<img src="" class="ggg" />
<img src="" class="ggg" />
<img src="" class="ggg" />
<img src="" class="ggg" />
<img src="" class="ggg" />
```